# Extract value from mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, document

I'm new to mongo, and I'm havind trouble to get only values from fields. Let's say I have this document

```
    {
  user: 'adam',
  sessions: {
   key1: some-value1,
   key2: some-value2
  }
}
```

and I want to get only "some-value2". Using find and projection I can get this output

`[ { key2: 'some-value2' } ]`

SOLVED!!!

It's a 2 steps code....

```
  let userList = await users.findOne('adam');
  
  let userList2 = userList.key2
```

this returns

```
some-value2
```

Thanks a lot to those who answered so quickly... I've been stuck for days with these... U guys are life savers!!! =D

Comment: queries return documents(one or more), you cant return for example values or arrays.
you always get documents, that can have fields with values or arrays or other documents,
to get the "some-value2" you have to do it in the driver with js code

Comment: If you're asking how to project just certain sub-fields, then you can use a period (`.`). For example - `sessions.key2`.

Comment: This looks like a job for [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)!

Comment: As simple as a two step findOne query...